# Scala collections: array groupBy and return array indexes for each group

Tags: scala, group-by, scala-collections

I have an array, something like that:

```
val a = Array("a", "c", "c", "z", "c", "b", "a")
```

and I want to get a map with keys of all different values of this array and values with a collection of relevant indexes for each such group, i.e. for a given array the answer would be:

```
Map(
  "a" -> Array(0, 6),
  "b" -> Array(5),
  "c" -> Array(1, 2, 4),
  "z" -> Array(3)
)
```

Surprisingly, it proved to be somewhat more complicated that I've anticipated. The best I've came so far with is:

```
a.zipWithIndex.groupBy {
  case(cnt, idx) => cnt
}.map {
  case(cnt, arr) => (cnt, arr.map {
    case(k, v) => v
  }
}
```

which is not either concise or easy to understand. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Your code can be rewritten as oneliner, but it looks ugly.

```
as.zipWithIndex.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Another way is to use [`mutable.MultiMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap)

```
import collection.mutable.{ HashMap, MultiMap, Set }

val as = Array("a", "c", "c", "z", "c", "b", "a")
val mm = new HashMap[String, Set[Int]] with MultiMap[String, Int]
```

and then just add every binding

```
as.zipWithIndex foreach (mm.addBinding _).tupled    
//mm = Map(z -> Set(3), b -> Set(5), a -> Set(0, 6), c -> Set(1, 2, 4))
```

finally you can convert it `mm.toMap` if you want immutable version.

Comment: I dont think the 1st one is ugly, matter of taste.

Comment: Maybe slightly less ugly one-liner `a.zipWithIndex.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.unzip._2)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version with `foldRight`. I think it's reasonably clear.

```
val a = Array("a", "c", "c", "z", "c", "b", "a") 
a
 .zipWithIndex
 .foldRight(Map[String, List[Int]]())
            {case ((e,i), m)=> m updated (e, i::m.getOrElse(e, Nil))}
//> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(a -> List(0, 6)
//| , b -> List(5), c -> List(1, 2, 4), z -> List(3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another version using `foldLeft` and an immutable `Map` with default value:

```
val a = Array("a", "c", "c", "z", "c", "b", "a")
a.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(Map[String, List[Int]]().withDefaultValue(Nil))( (m, p) => m + ((p._1, p._2 +: m(p._1))))

// res6: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(a -> List(6, 0), c -> List(4, 2, 1), z -> List(3), b -> List(5))
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting in `Scala 2.13`, we can use the new [groupMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Array.html#groupMap[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(implicitevidence$28:scala.reflect.ClassTag[B]):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Array[B]]) which (as its name suggests) is a one-pass equivalent of a `groupBy` and a `map`ping over grouped items:

```
// val a = Array("a", "c", "c", "z", "c", "b", "a")
a.zipWithIndex.groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
// Map("z" -> Array(3), "b" -> Array(5), "a" -> Array(0, 6), "c" -> Array(1, 2, 4))
```

This:

- zips each item with its index, giving `(item, index)` tuples
- `group`s elements based on their first tuple part (`_._1`) (group part of **group**Map)
- `map`s grouped values to their second tuple part (`_._2` i.e. their index) (map part of group**Map**)